# Combine 2 mp3 files by using FFmpeg

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I need to combine two mp3 files by using [ffMpeg](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java).
I use this code, but it doesn't work

I want to execute this

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

Why isn't my code working?

and my complete output log , problem Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'

```
        01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   built on Oct  7 2014 15:05:17 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
01-06 11:48:13.560 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/a.mp3':
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   Metadata:
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     title           : Creep
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     album           : Pablo Honey
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     track           : 2/13
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     disc            : 1/1
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     artist          : Radiohead
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     genre           : Alternative
-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     publisher       : EMI Music Distribution
-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     album_artist    : Radiohead
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     composer        : Colin Greenwood/Ed O'Brien/Jonny Greenwood/Phil Selway/Thom Yorke
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     date            : 1993
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   Duration: 00:03:55.91, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 320 kb/s
01-06 11:48:13.572 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
01-06 11:48:13.573 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     Metadata:
01-06 11:48:13.573 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout       encoder         : LAME3.97 
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout [mp3 @ 0x2b403a90] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout Input #1, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/b.mp3':
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   Metadata:
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     title           : This is Love                  
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     artist          : Chirs de Burgh                
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     album           : This Way Up                   
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     date            : 1994
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     comment         :                               
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout   Duration: 00:03:47.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
01-06 11:48:13.577 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout     Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
01-06 11:48:13.579 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: shellout Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
01-06 11:48:13.580 6119-6473/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/dalvikvm: threadid=14: exiting
01-06 11:48:13.580 6119-6473/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/dalvikvm: threadid=14: bye!
01-06 11:48:13.580 6119-6119/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/test: processComplete 1
01-06 11:48:13.580 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: exiting
01-06 11:48:13.581 6119-6472/com.uraroji.garage.android.mp3recvoice D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: bye!
```

Comment: try deleting all the spaces in the strings you are adding

Comment: Can you provide any actual error messages? You should probably add `-ac 2` output option to downmix to stereo, otherwise if you use amerge on two stereo inputs you can end up with a 4 channel output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard error massage : unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'  , ffmpeg: invalid argument

Comment: @LordNeckbeard and when replace ffmpeg with -y and attach -ac 2 return this error unknown encoder libmp3kame

Comment: You should show the **complete** output/log. There is no encoder named libmp3kame. Do you have a typo?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard   this is my problem: 01-06 10:48:41.629 1743-1957/org.ffmpeg.android D/test: shellout Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'    , i added libmp3lame.so in libs file but don't work

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i attach my log in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MP3 Encoder

FFmpeg does not have a native MP3 encoder, so you have to use an external library (libmp3lame or libshine) for MP3 encoding support. However, your `ffmpeg` build was not compiled with `--enable-libmp3lame` or `--enable-libshine`. You will have to re-compile `ffmpeg`.

libmp3lame is more common, but libshine is for fixed-point MP3 encoding which may be faster on your ARM device (but I've never performed any comparisons).

## amerge

Your command uses the [amerge](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter to merge two stereo audio files. This will result in a 4-channel output. If you want to downmix the output to stereo then add `-ac 2`.